# Hyperlinking to other files in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, file-format, hyperlink

What I’m finding is that hyperlinks to bookmarks in other existing files still won’t work because standard Word 2010 file format appears to be .xml, which doesn’t support bookmarks.
 You get this message:

> Certain file formats, such as XML, do not support bookmarks so you
>   cannot create a hyperlink to a bookmark in a file that does not
>   support bookmarks. You can either hyperlink to the file without any
>   bookmarks, or change the file format so you can insert bookmarks into
>   and hyperlink to the bookmark.

I need to know how to find out what file format supports bookmarks in Word 2010. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

Possibly creating a cross-reference as a hyperlink would work:

1. Move the cursor to the place where you want to link to be created.
2. Open the Cross-reference dialog box: On the Insert tab of the Ribbon, in the Links group, click Cross-reference.
3. In the Cross-reference dialog box, under Reference type, select Bookmark as the type of item that the link will target.
4. Under Insert reference to, select the type of text that will be displayed in the link.
5. Select the Insert as hyperlink check box if it is cleared.
6. Under For which bookmark, select the bookmark that will be the destination of the link.
7. Click Insert, and then click Close.
8. If you want your link to have the same underlining and color as a hyperlink, select the displayed text, press Ctrl+U to add underlining, and then press Ctrl+D. In the Font dialog box, click the Font color combo box, click the appropriate color (or create a custom color), and click OK.